# About building database for persian speech to text project

Tags: dataset, speech-to-text

In connection with the persian speech to text project on github, I am trying to collect the database from the audio and text available on the ganjoor site and Youtube Persian videos with Persian subtitles (also, Maybe compare to others database via internet like [this](https://appen.com/speech-language-datasets/product-catalog/?add_to_catalog_cart=show))

But since I am new to this fields, your help can be very It worked.

If it is possible, please help in how to properly save the audio and text by suggesting proper format for saving data and pre filtering for better sorting data like said [here](https://medium.com/ibm-watson/data-collection-and-training-for-speech-projects-22004c3e84fb). (Any python sample codes, would be very helpful.)

Project github site (Forked):

https://bit.ly/3hRIb1V

Ganjoor scraper page (text and audio collection):

https://bit.ly/3kGlijQ

Question related ( Ganjoor scraper codes):

https://bit.ly/3cnR8zd

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to consider using Persian songs which have the lyrics (i.e. متن) readily available as well. There are also Islamic eulogies, known as noheh (نوحه), which are essentially poems recited somewhat similar to songs and sometimes include the written poem (i.e. نسخه).

Some examples:
https://bit.ly/2FRnI0g
https://bit.ly/3mKpj8W